# Add validation dynamically to input ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript

I used NgForm to add a validator dynamically to the input

I have the button setValidation for set validation to input, in the first example everything works well, but in the second example when i add formGroup i get the below error when i click the button setValidation

> Cannot read property 'setValidators' of null

```
@ViewChild('f') myForm: NgForm;
coumNameModel;

setValidation() {
  this.myForm.form.get('coumnName').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"), Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(2)]);
  this.myForm.form.get('coumnName').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

**first example**

```
<form #f="ngForm">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="coumnNameModel" name="coumnName" #coumnName="ngModel">
</form>
<p *ngIf="!myForm.form.get('coumnName')?.valid">
    <i class="icons icon-cancel color-error"></i>
    <small class="color-error">Invalid</small>
</p>
<button (click)="setValidation()">Set Validation</button>
```

**second example**

```
<form [formGroup]="generalInformationForm" #f="ngForm">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="coumnNameModel" name="coumnName" #coumnName="ngModel" gDefaultControl
        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
</form>
<p *ngIf="!myForm.form.get('coumnName')?.valid">
    <i class="icons icon-cancel color-error"></i>
    <small class="color-error">Invalid</small>
</p>
<button (click)="setValidation()">Set Validation</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngmodule) documentaion ngForm diretive will be explicity initialized when there is no formGroup or ngNoForm.

```
**Selectors**
   form:not([ngNoForm]):not([formGroup])
   ng-form
   [ngForm]
```

In your second example you have used reactive form. So you have to use get method to access to information about a given control like this.

```
setValidation() {
  this.generalInformationForm.get('professionType').setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[0-9]*$"), Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(2)]);
  this.generalInformationForm.get('professionType').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Comment: It should be this.generalInformationForm
      .get("professionType")

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you used both `formGroup` and `ngForm` on the same form which shouldn't do.

Use either one. I recommend you to use reactive forms i.e. `formGroup`